# Column operation on Spark RDDs in Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have a RDD with MANY columns (e.g. hundreds), and most of my operation is on columns, e.g. I need to create many intermediate variables from different columns.

What is the most efficient way to do this?

I create a RDD from a CSV file:

```
dataRDD = sc.textFile("/...path/*.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(",”))
```

For example, this will give me an RDD like below:

```
123, 523, 534, ..., 893 
536, 98, 1623, ..., 98472 
537, 89, 83640, ..., 9265 
7297, 98364, 9, ..., 735 
...... 
29, 94, 956, ..., 758
```

I need to create a new column or a variable as calculatedvalue = 2ndCol+19thCol and create a new RDD.

```
123, 523, 534, ..., 893, calculatedvalue 
536, 98, 1623, ..., 98472, calculatedvalue 
537, 89, 83640, ..., 9265, calculatedvalue 
7297, 98364, 9, ..., 735, calculatedvalue 
...... 
29, 94, 956, ..., 758, calculatedvalue
```

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a map it would be enough:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize([(1,2,3,4), (4,5,6,7)])

# just replace my index with yours
newrdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x + (x[1] + x[2],)) 

newrdd.collect() # [(1,2,3,4,6), (4,5,6,7,12)]
```